# Multiple If with correlated echos

Tags: php, if-statement, upload

I am new to php. I have searched for a solution to this problem for over 1 hour but could not find an answer.

Example situation: Check uploaded file extension & size and echo out errors for each failure (if any)(stopping at first failure).

Code so far:

```
$allowedfiletypes = array("image/jpg","image/jpeg","image/png");
if((!in_array($filetype, $allowedfiletypes))) {
    echo "Error, disallowed file type.";
} elseif($filesize > 1048576) {
    echo 'Filesize too large';
} else {
    move_uploaded_file($filetmpname, $uploaddir."/".$filename);
    echo 'The file has the following properties:'." ".$filename.", ".$filesize."kb, ".$filetype.".".'<br><br>';
    echo ' The file is stored in'.$uploaddir.$filename;
}
```

But this does not work if the file size is over the specified limit.

How can i do `if() {echo 'error1';} || if {echo 'error2'.} else {}`?

Comment: If the first error shows, it won't bother executing the rest of the elseif/else blocks.

Comment: I don't see `$filesize` being defined.

Comment: I just want to be able to run two if conditions, and be able to echo out the error which describes the 1st or 2nd failure so i know what it is failing on if im an end user (example only).

Comment: is this code snippet in some function on in main php script?
Edit: so I assume that the main problem is that this function does not work when the filezie is over the limit, yes? What are the errors?

Answer (score 1):

Why not use flags?

```
$error1 = 1;
$error2 = 1;

if($error1 && $error2) { ... }
```

Or use an error counter and `die` if it reaches a particular count.

Comment: @Akshay Joshi - everything has been defined, this is just a code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure what you want, but if you want to display both errors to the user, this should work:

```
$allowedfiletypes = array("image/jpg","image/jpeg","image/png");
$fileTypes = true;
$fileSize = true;
if((!in_array($filetype, $allowedfiletypes)))
   $fileTypes = false;

if($filesize > 1048576)
    $fileSize = false;

if ($fileSize && $fileTypes) {
    move_uploaded_file($filetmpname, $uploaddir."/".$filename);
    echo '<p>The file has the following properties:'." ".$filename.", ".$filesize."kb, ".$filetype.".</p>";
    echo '<p>The file is stored in'.$uploaddir.$filename.'</p>';
}
else {
    if (!$fileSize)
        echo '<p>Filesize too large</p>';
    if (!$fileTypes)
        echo "<p>Error, disallowed file type.</p>";
}
```

Comment: Thanks OptimusCrime, i will look at that now. Just to be clear (finding it hard to explain), what im wanting is that if the upload fails on file type, a custom error for that is echoed out; if the file upload fails on size, a custom error for that is echoed out.

Comment: @user1011774: This should do what you want :)